# ImportError: cannot import name 'Deconvolution3D' from 'keras.layers' (/home/mona/venv/fall/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, deconvolution

How should I fix the following error?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Deconvolution3D' from 'keras.layers' (/home/mona/venv/fall/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py)
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-8ac95d90a6a0> in <module>
      4 import config
      5 from trainer.fusiondiffroigan import Params,Fusion_Diff_ROI_3DCAE_GAN3D
----> 6 from models import diff_ROI_C3D_AE_no_pool

~/research/code/GAN-fall/Fall-detection/mrfd/models.py in <module>
      5 from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Input, Reshape, BatchNormalization
      6 # from keras.layers import Conv3DTranspose as Deconvolution3D
----> 7 from keras.layers import Deconvolution3D
      8 from keras.optimizers import SGD
      9 from keras import regularizers

ImportError: cannot import name 'Deconvolution3D' from 'keras.layers' (/home/mona/venv/fall/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py)
```

I have:

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on Linux

$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, on TensorFlow 2, Deconvolution3D has been renamed Conv3DTranspose.
So you can use:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3DTranspose
```

So we now have a cleaner:

- Conv2D and its "reversed" Conv2DTranspose
- Conv3D and its "reversed" Conv3DTranspose

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Deconvolution3D
```